# pp chain gamma decay / intermediate state

Tags: nuclear-physics, fusion

Based on the first equation at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton%E2%80%93proton_chain_reaction

$$_1^{1}H+_1^{1}H \to _2^{2}He+\gamma$$

Is it correct to say that in the P-P chain two hydrogen atoms fuse to form a helium-2 isotope in an excited state which decays by gamma emission to a helium-2 isotope in a non-excited state, emitting a photon in the process?

$$_1^{1}H+_1^{1}H \to _2^{2}He^* \to _2^{2}He+\gamma$$

Or is it just a one-step process without excited helium-2 intermediate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a very general sense a lot of reaction that are written in one step can also be written in two. I.e. alpha capture on carbon-13<sup>1</sup> is often written 
$$\alpha + ^{13}\!\mathrm{C} \to ^{16}\!\mathrm{O} + \text{various photons and leptons} \,,$$ 
but may be written as one of
$$\begin{align} 
\alpha + ^{13}\!\mathrm{C} &\to ^{16}\!\mathrm{O} \\
\alpha + ^{13}\!\mathrm{C} &\to ^{16}\!\mathrm{O}^* \to ^{16}\!\mathrm{O} + e^+ + e^-\\
\alpha + ^{13}\!\mathrm{C} &\to ^{16}\!\mathrm{O}^{**} \to ^{16}\!\mathrm{O} + \gamma\,(\text{6.05 MeV}) \\
\dots
\end{align}$$

However, in order for that to be reasonable, there must be a bound intermediate state to talk about.

In the case of PP fusion [there is no bound $^2\mathrm{He}$ state](http://ie.lbl.gov/education/parent/He_iso.htm) (much less a bound excited state).<sup>2</sup> Fusion only results if there is a weak tranformation at a time when both protons are very close to one another.

Nor can we talk about one proton turning into a neutron and then finding the other proton, because that intermediate state is energetically forbidden.

So, long story short, **I don't think that you should write the proton-proton fusion process with an intermediate state**. It's all or nothing.

---

<sup>1</sup> A reaction selected entirely because I know it well.

<sup>2</sup> Contrast this with the oxygen system where the excited states are real and have been studied in detail by neutron knock-out reaction on Oxygen-17.

Comment: Fair enough but my question wasn't "should I write it with an intermediate state" but "is it happening with an intermediate state". So if I understood it correctly  you are saying that it does happen with an intermediate state but we don't write it down for obvious reasons (clarity / we can always decompose things further until it takes 50 pages to explain 1 + 1 = 2) ?

Comment: No, there is no intermediate state. That's the point. Is has to happen in one step.

Comment: Could you briefly clarify what you mean by "bound intermediate state" and why there is one in the case of gamma emission? (I am a freshman)

Comment: An unbound state is one in which the constituents has enough energy to escape to arbitrarily large distance; bound systems do not. The two protons are *always* have escape energy because the residual strong attraction between them is less than the Coulomb repulsion.